# status: 400, message: There is some trouble to proceed your action!, data: null

Tags: flutter, api, http, dart, flutter-dependencies

want upload image from gallery or camera to api here is my image api

```
Future  profileImageUser(String user_id, String image) async {

      String url = 'api';
      final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
          body: {
            'user_id': user_id,
            'image': image
          }
      );
      var convertedDataJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return convertedDataJson;
    }
```

Here is how i am getting user id and image to upload it through rest api.

```
  Future _imgFromCamera() async {
    final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);


    setState(() {
      _image = image;
      final bytes = File(_image!.path).readAsBytesSync();
      String img64 = base64Encode(bytes);
     print(img64);
    });
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      
      var myId = prefs.getString('user_id');
      print(myId);
      var myProfile = _image;
      print(myProfile); 
      var rsp = await profileImageUser(
        myId.toString(),
        myProfile.toString(),
        
      );
      print(rsp);
       if (rsp['status'] == true) {
        print(rsp);
      } else {
        print('failed');
      }
    }
```

when i upload image from gallery or camera it print id and image as follow

```
I/flutter ( 6665): Instance of 'XFile'
I/flutter ( 6665): 111
```

but it also show the following error

```
{status: 400, message: There is some trouble to proceed your action!, data: null}
```

here is my postman api parameter

key: user_id
value: 76
key: image
value: data:image/jpeg;base64,(and other data)

any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the issue basically i was not correctly converting image in base 64 here is how you should do

```
Future createAlbum(String user_id , File image) async {
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('api'),
   /* headers: {
      'Accept': 'multipart/form-data'
    },*/
    body: {
      'user_id': user_id,
      'image': selectedImage != null ? 'data:image/png;base64,' +
          base64Encode(selectedImage!.readAsBytesSync()) : '',
    },
  );

  final responseJson = await json.decode(json.encode(response.body));

  print(responseJson);
}
```